# Hello ,my app crashes every time I invoke Spinner which exists in a Fragment called "Firstfragment"

Tags: java, android, spinner

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


//This Spinner is not located in the MainActivity but in A fragment
        Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner33);

        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                       long arg3) {
                String msupplier=s.getSelectedItem().toString();
                 
                    Log.e("Selected item : ", msupplier);

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

              
            }
        });
```

//Main MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/drawer">

<include

    layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"


    android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

//first Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/Fragment1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#2196F3"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="773dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/background"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/teal_700"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/watBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_looks_one_24"
        android:editable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="auto"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:includeFontPadding="true"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:onClick="WattMthd"
        android:text="@string/WAT"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="35dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="129dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ampBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_looks_two_24"
        android:editable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="ampMthd"
        android:text="@string/AMP"
        android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/voltBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_looks_3_24"
        android:editable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="voltMthd"
        android:text="فولت"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/kWbtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_looks_4_24"
        android:editable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="kWMthd"
        android:text="كيلو"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
</LinearLayout>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner33"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"

    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
    android:entries="@array/SpinerConvertFrom"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_drop_down_circle_24"
    android:foregroundGravity="left|center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:flow_verticalAlign="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner33">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/Text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/AMP"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/Volt"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: so then you can't use findViewById like that, use it where the component is

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but I did not get it .. I am new to Android and your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the spinner initialization from the fragment but it exists in the main activity it will crash, you need to call it in the activity, or move it to the xml of the framgnet.

Comment: Thank you ---The Opposite , I am calling the spinner initialization from the main activity but it exists in the fragment .

Answer (score 0):

activity_main belongs to MainActivity. So there is a fragment_first which belongs to FirstFragment. The spinner you are trying to initialize belongs to fragment_first, so you have to use it inside FirstFragment or move it (spinner) to activity_main

Comment: Thank you , I actually used it inside its fragment activity but cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

Comment: In a fragment you have to use the view to get access to the method findViewById. You have to initialize your view. Something like this:
`@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);
        Spinner sp = v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        return v;
    }
`

Comment: The code does not have any errors now , but when I click on the spinner nothing happens.

Comment: Did you initialize `s.setOnItemSelectedListener` ?

Comment: Yes I did initialize it in the same Fragment Class

Comment: `code`         s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                       long arg3) {
                String msupplier=s.getSelectedItem().toString();
                s.setVisibility(View.GONE);//to Test it
                Log.e("Selected item : ", msupplier);

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });

Comment: The other items in this fragment work fine when the are invoked in MainActivity.java

Comment: Can u show me the content of activity_main.xml and fragment_first.xml

Comment: sorry for bothering but I am exhausted soling this problem.. maybe you can help me with this  : I have a button in the same fragment and I want to Set the visibility of it to Gone..My app Crashes when coding this in mainactivity:::  Button ss=(Button)findViewById(R.id.watBtn);
        ss.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to use views from the fragment in the activity. If the button is in fragment, you should set visibility.GONE of button in the fragment

Answer (score 0):

Hi bro inside you activity_main.xml you didn't define spinner, so you can't get view which you didn't create in your xml file, you can get it from your fragment, or you must move Spinner to activity_main.xml.

Comment: Thank you but how can I get it from my fragment and use it normally in class MainActivity without moving the spinner from the fragment

Comment: Afeef why you want use spinner in MainActivity, if will explain me your task or problem, may be i can suggest you right solution.